# Error Calculating MVN Likelihood of Time Series with AR(1) Errors in R

Tags: time-series, covariance-matrix

I'm having trouble calculating the likelihood of a time series with AR(1) errors. I am generating my covariance matrix according to page 2 of (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contri...regression.pdf), using the library mvtnorm and the multivariate normal density function dmvnorm(). Here's some example code:

```
library(mvtnorm)

# Generate a basic time series with AR(1) Errors:

t <- 1:100

error <- as.numeric(arima.sim(n = length(t), list(ar = c(0.8897)), sd = 10))

series <- 5*t + error

# Fit the series using a basic linear model assuming errors are IID Normal

naive.model <- lm(series ~ t -1)

# Examine and model the residuals

residuals <- series - t*coef(naive.model)

residual.model <-  arima(residuals, c(1,0,0), include.mean=F)

# Construct the covariance matrix, assuming the process variance (10^2) is known

sigma <- diag(length(t))

sigma[(abs(row(sigma)-col(sigma)) == 1)] = as.numeric(coef(residual.model))

sigma <- sigma*10^2

# Calculate the MVN density...

dmvnorm(series, t*coef(naive.model) ,sigma, log=T)
```

Without fail, I get the following error message:

```
Warning message: In log(eigen(sigma, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE)$values) : NaNs produced.
```

It's worth noting that the matrix from the following (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-hel...ay/131728.html) "works", but I think is actually for an MA(1) process rather than an AR(1) process.

I gather the message means the proposed covariance matrix may not be invertible. This said I'm stuck on how to proceed and would be extremely appreciative of any thoughts.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

Your covariance matrix construction is incorrect. In particular, you have a tridiagonal matrix, but an AR(1) covariance matrix has no zeros. The offdiagonal elements should have correlations that are the AR(1) coefficient raised to the difference in times between the two observations, i.e. the difference between the row and column number.

Define sigma using this code:

```
D     = diag(length(t))
rho   = coef(residual.model)
corr  = rho^abs(row(D)-col(D))
sigma = 10^2/(1-rho^2) * corr
```

This AR(1) covariance matrix construction in R was taken from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-May/131728.html).

Comment: You forgot to multiply by the variance, which depends on rho. The correct code would be `sigma=rho^abs(row(Sigma)-col(Sigma))/(1-rho^2)`, where `rho=coef(residual.model)`

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I have updated my answer to fully define sigma.